# How to indicate the level of the for loop in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function including a `for` loop part. This `for` loop will work for, say, `10` iteration. How can I know from the result that the function is working now at level (iteration) number, say, `5`.

That is, I would like my function to let me know the current iteration number.

For example, 
I would like the result to be such this:

`Iteration 1 starts`

`some result`

`iteration 1 ends`

`iteration 2 starts`

`some result`

`iteration 2 ends`
...
...

**Please note this is not my original function**. In my original function I use `optim` function over a list of models, and I really need to know what is the current model.

Here is a general example:

```
Myfun <- function(x,y){
  v <- list()
  for(i in 1:100){
    v[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]], y[[i]])
    cat(v, "\n")

  }
  v
}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
Myfun(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: You could output the current iteration step inside the `for` loop, e.g. `cat(sprintf("Step %i/100\n", i))`; or use a progress bar, see e.g. `?txtProgressBar`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers. thanks so much for your comment. could you please pass it as an answer.

Comment: No problem, I've added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1

Output the current iteration step inside the `for` loop.

```
Myfun <- function(x,y) {
    v <- list()
    for (i in 1:100) {
        v[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]], y[[i]])
        cat(sprintf("Step %i / 100 done\n", i))
    }
    v
}
```

---

### Method 2

Use a progress bar (see `?txtProgressBar` for details).

```
Myfun <- function(x,y) {
    v <- list()
    pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 100, style = 3)
    for (i in 1:100) {
        v[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]], y[[i]])
        setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    }
    close(pb)
    v
}
```

Note that the line `cat(v, "\n")` from your original `Myfun` will give an error.

Comment: Amazing help. It is really most appreciated.